# In-tag 'onload' JS has no effect on the target

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this line in one of my `html.twig` templates.

`<div class="panel panel-default" onload="(this.class = determineClass(this))">`

and later:

```
var determineClass = function(element) {
    if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) {
        return element.class + ' some_class';
    } else {
        return element.class + ' some_other_class';
    }
}
```

I expected the string in `onload` to be executed as JS. However, the string is interpreted literally and has no effect on the `class` of that tag.

How could I use `determineClass` function to alter the `class` attribute of this tag ?

Comment: Just curious--I see you want to add `some_class` or `some_other_class` based on overflow; what kinds of things would they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my knowledge, you cannot use `onload` on a div. Using JQuery, here is a  way to go (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/6xwo9bd8/2/)).

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-default determineClass"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.determineClass').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('determineClass');
    if ($(this).offsetHeight < $(this).scrollHeight) {
      $(this).addClass('some_class');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('some_other_class');
    }
  });
});
```

The `ready` ensure that the function runs after the document if fully loaded. I use the class `determineClass` as a flag, to label the elements which need to be processed.

Once the document is loaded, I iterate through all the labelled elements, remove the flag class and do the actual processing.

Comment: @Zim84 I use a "label" class to know which div need to be processed. I wait until the document is loaded, then fetch all the divs with the "label" class, remove it, and do the actual job. What bothers you/don't you understand ?

Comment: I fully understand it, but others might not since you only pasted some chunks of code without further explaining whats going on and why. Lets change your answer from technically correct to a great answer!

Comment: @Zim84 I am still kind of new to stackoverflow. Dully noted, will do better next time! Thanks for the precious advice. *edit*: changed the answer.

Comment: That'd be indeed one of the ways to solve the problem.  I however, opted for writing a custom jQuery plugin to manipulate DOM. I will soon post my solution, too.